# Append text on a file in on bash script

Tags: bash

I'm using cat to append some results in a file but the file its empty after the execution

```
start="$(date +'%s%3N')"
sleep 1
echo $par 
end="$(date +'%s%3N')"

duration=$(($end-$start))
cat  "$par $duration" >> result.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

`echo "$par $duration" >> result.dat`

You use `cat` which will echo the content of the file with the name formed by `"$par $duration"`. This will most likely not exist, so that you end up appending nothing to result.dat.